# How to use Braintree V Zero on IOS app?

Tags: ios, braintree

I am coding an IOS app with Payment feature. 
I decided to use Braintree V Zero.

At the very beginning, I use their excellent DropIn UI feature, and everything works fine.
But when payment happen, the Drop In UI required end-user to input his credit card or Paypal information every time.

Does any expect know how to implement one automatic charge solution by BrainTree V zero?

Like Uber's charge solution.

I guess maybe need to mark the user's credit card information from app side or service side?

```
    router.get('/token', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Kevin in token be called %s', req.param('aCustomerId'));
  var aCustomerId = req.param('aCustomerId');
  console.log('Kevin %s', aCustomerId);
  gateway.clientToken.generate({customerId: aCustomerId}, function (error, response) {
    res.send(response.clientToken);
    console.log(response.clientToken);
  });
});
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

The Braintree drop-in will [display previously used payment methods for a customer](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/ios/#customer-id), if you pass the `customer_id` in when [generating a client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/node#generate-a-client-token) on your server.
​
Here's an example of how to do it in Node:

```
gateway.clientToken.generate({
  customerId: aCustomerId
}, function (err, response) {
  var clientToken = response.clientToken
});
```

​
Once a payment method is used, it will be saved in the drop-in and the customer will not have to enter it again. Pass the token of the saved payment method when creating a transaction:
​

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
  amount: "10.00",
  paymentMethodToken: theToken,
  options: {
    submitForSettlement: true
  }
}, function (err, result) {
});
```

If you have any further questions, please feel free to contact [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).
3133e

Comment: I have tried. My Service side are using Node JS.  @Jessica d , then my server said undefined error.

Comment: Noel, do you mean to use req.params('aCustomerId'); on the third line of your code snippet? If you are still having trouble, please reach out to Braintree support so we can get more details of your integration.
https://support.braintreepayments.com

Comment: Jessica, yes, I used req.params('aCustomerId'); to generation token, but it response me undefined. Do you know why?

Comment: My aCustomerId is a wrong one. Should it be created by Customer.create() ? Right? Where is the best place to create the customer under my scenario? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you Jessica, yes I need to create new customer ID in advanced, then your suggestion solution is working.

Comment: Please reach out to Braintree support so we can get more details of your integration. support.braintreepayments.com